# RethinkDB JavaScript Date Filter

Tags: javascript, date, filter, rethinkdb

I'm trying to query only things that are less than a day old... in JS this returns true; Why is rethink not returning true, so also not returning any results?

```
r.db( "db" ).table("table")
  .filter( function (item) {
    var
        now = new Date(),
        then = new Date( item.upload_date );
    return now - then > 1000*60*60*24
  });
```

I've tried this as well:

```
r.db( "db" ).table("table")
  .filter( function (item) {
    var
        now = new Date(),
        then = new Date( item( "upload_date") );
    return now - then > 1000*60*60*24
  });
```

EDIT: It's definitely my `item( "upload_date" )` is not returning the date string... what should I be using there instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReQL is smart enough to parse strings and sort them. If you have your date in the correct format it should still filter with an `.lt` on the row.

```
r.db("database").table("table")
    .filter( r.row('upload_date')
    .lt( new Date( new Date() - (24*60*60*1000) ).toISOString().replace(/\..{4}/, '').replace(/T/, ' ') ) )
```

--
Cheers

### --EDIT--

#### ( For learning or testing use Regex101.com )

Requested Regular Expression in `String.replace()` method:

**FIRST** - ( Dump the end of the time code )

eg: "2017-03-20T17:17:37.966Z" -> "2017-03-20T17:17:37"

- Find the first literal period. `\.`
- -> And ANY 4 characters after that`.{4}`

Replace the above group them with empty quote, or nothing

**SECOND** -

eg: "2017-03-20T17:17:37" -> "2017-03-20 17:17:37"

- Find the first instance of the character `T`

Replace above group with a space character or " "

This sets the string to be able to compare inside rethink db

## NOTICE: RethinkDB as a project has been dropped, but will be open sourced. Consider other resources for your projects if you require support.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstood ReQL. The filter function is supposed to be run on servers, not on your client.

You have to change it to this:

```
r.db( "db" ).table("table")
  .filter(r.now().sub(r.row('upload_date')).lt(60*60*24))
```

`r.now()` returns current time, assume that `upload_date` is stored in native RethinkDB time, you can sub tract two time value, the result is how many second elapses. Then you can compare with 60*60*24(how many seconds in a day)

Written in function style it will be

```
r.db( "db" ).table("table")
  .filter(function(item) {
     return r.now().sub(item('upload_date')).lt(60*60*24))
  })
```

It may confuse that the way it is written looks like raw JavaScript. But that's not the case. In fact, the client driver will evaluate function on client, to **build the query**, into a JSON string that RethinkDB understands and send it to the server. It doesn't run on client to execute logic of comparing. It generates a JSON string to tell RethinkDB what it wants using the API that is available on http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript. More information about how driver works: http://rethinkdb.com/docs/writing-drivers/

Second, if you `upload_date` isn't in a native RethinkDB time object, you can try to convert it to RethinkDB time type for easily manipulation with some of these functions:

- iso8601 time: http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/iso8601/
- epoch_time: http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/epoch_time/

Or just try to post your time here and we will help you out.

Comment: I was trying to avoid re-writing my script to use epoch_time, but I think as good practices I should just do it, so nice write up, but I'd already read all that, and certainly was running it in a server in a docker container that is managed in an EC2 instance in the amazon... but thanks.

Comment: ... also just because I was curious but pretty sure I tried you solution, my instincts were right... it's string data, needs to be cast to a date, and that breaks something somewhere along the way and poof magically doesn't work

Comment: Yeah...data type is the problem here. You have to fix it and convert it. But the way you write it makes me think you misunderstand ReQL. `item.upload_date` is invalid syntax to access field, `item("upload_date")` is how you write it.

Comment: I figured that out as well... notice my second example